# Finding the Cauchy Principal Value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-i}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

I know that the Cauchy Principal value of

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-i}dx=i\pi$

but I do not understand how to get to this. I understand how to use the principal value for functions with real poles, but with this integral I always end up struggling with the fact that going to the complex plane the integral over the half circle in the upper half plane does not go to zero as $R\rightarrow\infty$. Any suggestions?

Comment: $\frac 1 {x-i}=\frac {x+i} {x^{2}+1}$. Split the integral into two terms.